# Error message: failed to allocated device memory for long state

Tags: cryptonight, ccminer

Trying to execute ccminer-cryptonight through powershell and finally hit an impasse. Any ideas?

edit:attempting to nvidia mine using 1080ti

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUirz.jpg)

Comment: It looks like the miner is trying to allocate more memory than is available. You can try to decrease the number of mining threads, which should decrease the amount of memory needed proportionally.

Comment: So I'm dropping to 28 blocks @ 8 threads?

Comment: Whatever will work.